# Javascript syntax invalid in Safari / Webkit, works fine in Chrome / Firefox

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, each, map-function

I have this function which works perfectly in Chrome and Firefox, but returns a SyntaxError: Unexpected token '>' in Safari / Webkit.

What would the Safari-safe way of writing this function be?

```
data = _.each(data, obj =>  {
     _.map(obj.QUESTIONS, q => {
        if (q.ANSWER) {
            q.HAS_ANSWER = 1;
        }
        return q;
     });
});
```

Comment: [Arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) are not supported by Safari. Just use the normal `function`s.

Comment: http://caniuse.com/#search=arrow - use a `function(obj) { ... }` expression

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fat arrows `=>` are part of ES6 and aren't yet supported in some Browsers.
Instead do this:

```
data = _.each(data, function(obj){
    _.map(obj.QUESTIONS, function(q){
       if (q.ANSWER) {
           q.HAS_ANSWER = 1;
       }
       return q;
    });
});
```